# Javascript array - how to handle multiple array items with same key/name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript array like this (end result):

```
Array(
   [text_vars] => Array(
      [0] => 'xxxxxx',
      [1] => 'xxxxxx'
   )
)
```

Right now the loop I'm using to translate my JSON data into the array:

```
var aws = json.data;
var text_vars = new Array();

for(i=0; i < 4; i++){
   var id = aws[i]['id'];
   var name = aws[i]['name'];           
   text_vars[i] = id;
}
```

I then post the resulting array to my PHP processing page, I send them along with my jQuery post in this format:

```
{ text_vars: text_vars }
```

I need the array formatted like this:

```
Array(
   [text_vars][0] => 'xxxxx',
   [text_vars][1] => 'xxxxx'
)
```

The end goal is to prepare the data so it's ready to be posted via jQuery, like this:

```
{ text_vars[0]: 'xxxxx', text_vars[1]: 'xxxxx' }
```

So, if you can suggest a better method to transform the array into that format, I'm happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = {}

for (var i = 0; i < text_vars.length; ++i) {
  result["text_vars[" + i + "]"] = text_vars[i]
}
```

Now `result` contains the structure you desire.

Comment: thanks dude! simple question but its been a while since I used js and it was driving me nuts!